# How to use `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` is touched correctly to send data from one view controller to a detail view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a map annotation that I would like to push to a detail view controller when the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` is touched. The problem I'm having is that all annotations all send the same data to the detail vc. I'm not sure if it's the indexPath that's incorrect. Each map annotation shows the correct info in the callout box, it's just that when the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` is tapped it pushes the same info for the first listing in the array it seems.

It's the     `NSNumber *catListingMapId`; in the annotation that I really need to access and pass to the detail vc (and there I download data based on that catListingMapId).

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)pin calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    MyAnnotation *theAnnotation = (MyAnnotation *) pin.annotation;

    NSLog(@"the Annotation %@",theAnnotation.catListingMapId);

    detailViewController.listingId = theAnnotation.catListingMapId;
  //  detailViewController.listingId = [[self.listingNodesArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath] objectForKey:@"id"];

    NSNumber *catNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[catID intValue]];

    detailViewController.catId = catNumber;

    NSLog(@"detailViewController.listingId  %@",detailViewController.listingId );
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

here's my myAnntoationMap file:

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {

CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
NSString*               title;
NSString*               subtitle;
NSNumber *latString;
NSNumber *lngString;

NSNumber *catMapId;
NSNumber *catListingMapId;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               title;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               subtitle;

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *latString;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *lngString;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *catMapId;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *catListingMapId;

@end


and the .m

    #import "MyAnnotation.h"

@implementation MyAnnotation

@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;
@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize latString,lngString;
@synthesize catMapId;
@synthesize catListingMapId;

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
    self.title = nil;
    self.subtitle = nil;
    self.latString = nil;
    self.lngString = nil;
    self.catMapId = nil;
    self.catListingMapId = nil;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MKMapViewDelegate having following delegate method,which is  called every time when ever user tapped on calloutAccessory button, so here we get annotation title and subtitle,By using these values you can pass data to next viewController

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"%@",view.annotation.title);
    NSLog(@"%@",view.annotation.subtitle);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried that with NSLog(@"%@",view.annotation.title); but     NSLog(@"%@ pin subtitle",view.annotation.catListingMapId); is unrecognized.

Comment: your nslog is wrong.: NSLog(@"%d", [catListingMapId integerValue]); . You want to log a NSNumber, not a NSString. %@ is for NSString, for log int: %i or %d

Answer (score 1):

```
detailViewController.listingId = theAnnotation.catListingMapId
```

and in detailViewController find the other details by listingID

EDIT:

in

```
@interface MyAnnotation
```

write a method:

```
- (NSDictionary *) getTheAnnotationData{
    NSDictionary* theDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latString],@"latString",
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lngString],@"lngString",
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",catMapId],@"catMapId",
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",catListingMapId],@"catListingMapId",
                             title,@"title",
                             subtitle,@"subtitle",
                             nil];

    return theDict;
}
```

This method will give you all data from your annotation in a dictionary.

write it into .h too:

```
- (NSDictionary *) getTheAnnotationData;
```

then:

make a property in `DetailViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary* detailDictionary;
```

then:

in your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)pin calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    MyAnnotation *theAnnotation = (MyAnnotation *) pin.annotation;

    NSLog(@"the Annotation %@",theAnnotation.catListingMapId);

    detailViewController.detailDictionary = [theAnnotation getTheAnnotationData];

    NSLog(@"detailViewController.listingId  %@",detailViewController.listingId );
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

then in detailViewController:

```
@ synthesize detailDictionary
```

and in `viewDidload`:

you could get all of your data what you want about your annotation

I hope it helps

Comment: I tried that and it was giving a -[MKPointAnnotation catListingMapId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Comment: I can access it like this:         NSNumber *listingIdNumber = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        
        annotation.subtitle = [listingIdNumber stringValue]; but then I lose the address and the id is part of the annotation.subtitle

Comment: you added a comment at the accepted answer.: your nslog is wrong.: NSLog(@"%d", [catListingMapId integerValue]); . You want to log a NSNumber, not a NSString. %@ is for NSString, for log int: %i or %d

Answer (score 1):

What has the index of the selected row (`[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]`) got to do with the annotation that someone has selected on the map? And where does `catID` come from?

If you want to show something on the `detailViewController` that is related to the annotation that someone has just pressed then you need to use info from the `pin`, currently you are using two data points that do not come from that pin, and are probably the same every time, so that's what you see on the `detailViewController`.